# Debian apache2 not found

Tags: apache2, debian

I have a problem with installing apache2 on Debian. When I try to install I get

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2
```

This is my repo (`/etc/apt/sources.list`)

```
#deb http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy main

#deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
#deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
#deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
```

And when I try to type `apt-cache search apache2` it return null(empty line)

Comment: You have an error in your search command. It should be: `apt-cache search apach2`. You might want to filter the results as well with: `apt-cache search apache2 | grep ^apache2` (useful when you are fairly certain that the package you are searching for will exist as it's own entry in the Debian repository.)

Answer (score 2):

do this

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the # character at the beginning of each line.

deb repo are for binary packages

deb-src repo are for source packages

Answer (score 0):

As @nurza said, you have to enable binary repos, erase the "#" on lines that begins with #deb. Your first line on /etc/apt/sources.list should have:

```
deb http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy main
```